# Recursive sequence.square root 3. Find the recursion ratio

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

$$\begin{cases}
{a_n} = 3a_{n-1} - 3a_{n-2} + a_{n-3}\\
{a_0} = 1, a_1=2, a_2=5
\end{cases}$$

Hey everyone..  So far I have solved only questions of 2 root kind. I tried to solve this one but no success.. I dont know what do to after i found out:

$$x^{3} - 3x^{2} + 3{x} - 1 = 0$$
equals to:
$$(x-1)^{3}$$

Aaaand lost.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2987595/42969.

Comment: @MartinR its different because here i need to solve the recursion ratio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- When root is simple you get $(a)x^n$
- When root is double you get $(an+b)x^n$
- When root is triple you get $(an^2+bn+c)x^n$

And so on...

Here $x=1$ is triple root, so the solution is $a_n=(an^2+bn+c)\times 1^n=an^2+bn+c$

Now search for initial conditions.

$\begin{cases}
a_0=c=1\\
a_1=a+b+c=2\\
a_2=4a+2b+c=5\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}
a=1\\
b=0\\
c=1\end{cases}\quad$  and you get $a_n=n^2+1$

Comment: THANK YOU! amazing

Answer (score 2):

Here you can use $b_n=a_n-a_{n-1}$ so that $b_n=2b_{n-1}-b_{n-2}$ and you have reduced the problem to something you should be able to solve.

If you have a multiple root $\alpha$ of order $m+1$ (here the root $x=1$ of order $3$) you will find that the test solution $a_n=p(n)\alpha^n$ is the one to use, where $p(n)$ is a polynomial of degree $m$. Here you would try $p(n)=An^2+Bn+C$ (a quadratic). That should accord with what you know about double roots.

Comment: Exactly. thanks for that. I will try with it now. one thing - if it was from root 4, then i should have irhgt $p(n)=An^{3}+Bn^{2}+Cn+D$ ?

Comment: @LorinSherry If you have a quadruple root you have a cubic as you have suggested.

Comment: alright. thank you